# Hydrate an Eloquent model object from associative array with more keys than database columns

Tags: php, eloquent

I have a database table called `players` with columns `id`, `name`, and `team`. The program is using [Eloquent](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent) in the [Slim](https://www.slimframework.com/) framework.

```
<?php
// ... correct `require` and `use` lines ....

class Player extends Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model {
    protected $guarded = [];
}

$input = ['id'   => 4, 
          'name' => 'James Shelton', 
          'team' => 'Astrobots', 
          'year' => 1982];

$player = new Player($input);
$player->save();
```

The above code produces an error about the table not having a 'year' column. I have also tried the methods [`hydrate`](https://laravel.com/api/5.3/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.html#method_hydrate) and [`fill`](https://laravel.com/api/5.3/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.html#method_fill).

What is the correct way to hydrate an Eloquent model object from an associative array and have the object only pay attention to array keys that match columns in the model's database table? Or am I incorrectly using the methods?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to specify list of the fillable fields to match your db schema:

```
class Player extends Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model {
    protected $fillable = [
      'id', 
      'name', 
      'team'
    ] 
}
```

Read "Mass Assignment" part from https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent

Comment: For me, `$player->getFillable()` is an empty array. I should also mention that, I believe, I have already unguarded all the model object's properties (the question has been updated to reflect this).

Comment: Ah, missed the part that error comes from the db. I have updated the answer. BTW, `protected $guarded = [];` and `static $ungarded = true` are different things, but it doesn't matter in your case.

Comment: While this does work, it seems to require that the list of columns be maintained in two places (the database and the class). I was hoping for a solution where the model was able to intrinsically know which columns were in the database table, similar to the [ADOdb](https://github.com/ADOdb/ADOdb) library.

Comment: Well, the page behind the link has quite clear reasoning why "Eloquent models protect against mass-assignment by default". Can't say I personally find it extremely elegant, but I believe that community behind the framework have some strong usecases to keep it this way.